# How to get relationship with union in eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

How can I make relationship with `union` in laravel eloquent? I've already tried two different approaches.

```
 User::with(['url' => function($query) use(&$some_property) {
    $favouriteUrls = \DB::table('urls')
        ->select('urls.*')
        ->join('favourite_urls', function($join) {
            $join->on('favourite_urls.url_id', '=', 'urls.id');
        })
        ->where('some_condition', '=', $some_property);

    $query = $query->union($favouriteUrls);
}]);
```

In the first attempt there wasn't any union in the query. Then I tried to move the logic to the model.

```
class User extends \Eloquent {
    public function urls() {
        $favouriteUrls = \DB::table('urls')
            ->select('urls.*')
            ->join('favourite_urls', function($join) {
                $join->on('favourite_urls.url_id', '=', 'urls.id');
            })
            ->where('some_condition', '=', $this->some_property);

        return $this->belongsTo('Url')->union($favouriteUrls);
    }
}
```

It has executed successfully but `$this->some_property` was set inside the query to the `null` value.

I can't create two separate relationship in this case. It has to be one with union. How can I fix it?

Comment: could you please provide code on how are you calling the query to retrieve the data?

Answer (score 1):

If you call that relation as `User::with('urls')` you will get that `$this->some_property` doesn't exists, because the object itself doesn't exists. But if you call the `urls()` method on an object, it should work. Something like this:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->urls; // here $this->some_property should have a value
```

Assuming you're calling the `urls()` method from a `User` object, the `$this->some_property` should give you the value. If for some reason you cannot access a property directly on an Eloquent model you can always refer to the `attributes[]` array inside of the model. For example

```
// calling
$this->some_property

// should be the same as
$this->attributes['some_property']
```

### Fetch all the users joining with the condition

Assuming `users` is the table for all the users, in your query you could change `$this->some_property` with `'users.some_property'` and everything should work as expected, for each user it will query based on that property. Here is the code:

```
class User extends \Eloquent {
    public function urls() {
        $favouriteUrls = \DB::table('urls')
            ->select('urls.*')
            ->join('favourite_urls', function($join) {
                $join->on('favourite_urls.url_id', '=', 'urls.id');
            })
        ->where('some_condition', '=', 'users.some_property');

        return $this->belongsTo('Url')->union($favouriteUrls);
    }
}
```

And then just call the method like this:

```
User::with('urls')->get();
```

Comment: It doesn't work. The array's empty. The method is probably executed before the query. The model is fulfilled afterwards.

Comment: @MateuszNowak I updated the answer to be a little bit more explicit, please review.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. There is still a problem. I need to fetch several `users` from database, not one. Do you have any idea how can I do that?

Comment: have you tried changing `$this->some_property` with `'users.some_property'`. Assuming the table for the Users is `users`. It should work as expected! Will update the answer with it.

Comment: It doesn't work. No matter what string I put in place of `$this->some_property`  I get query similar to `(SELECT * FROM urls WHERE urls.id in ('the string here',  ..'3910')) union (SELECT urls.* FROM urls inner join favourite_urls on favourite_urls.url_id = urls.id WHERE favourite_urls. the string here = '3911')` . The place of the string is swaped with integer value `3911` from `in` clause instead of desired model value.

Comment: @MateuszNowak didn't get this part `WHERE favourite_urls. the string here = '3911'`, I think I don't get exactly what you want to do.